# dynamic 100% height on element with float

Tags: css

This is bugging me for the past hour and can't figure it out. Here's a test case to better understand the scenario http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/RvTe7/1/

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
.header {
    height: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    height: 90%
}
    #side-bar {
        height: 100%;
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #content-zone {
        height: 100%;
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>test case</h1>
</div>
<div class="content clearfix">
    <div id="side-bar">menu</div>
    <div id="content-zone">page content <button>add more</button></div>
</div>
```

I can set the initial height of both my floating elements successfully to be 100%. The problem is new content will be added dynamically and the floated containers do not expand as I would expect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: position of floating elements is like fixed, so 100% is document height, not content height or something along those lines. Also good question on how to work around this so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is enough for you that only the yellow box grows , so you can do it like:

```
#content-zone {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RvTe7/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this

add below class `#content-zone{ 
               overflow-y:Scroll;
                }`

http://jsfiddle.net/RvTe7/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can change `height`, to `min-height`

```
#content-zone {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```